# Change arrow accordion bootstrap with image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i've use bootstrap accordion with toogle arrow, i use this example, here is the jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/zessx/r6eaw/12/

The question is if i want to change arrow with image, what i must editing ? or how to implement it. this the image i want to use it.
[if the accordion is open i use the image arrow bottom, and if the accordion is closed i use the image right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xd2NF.jpg)

```js
function toggleChevron(e) {
    $(e.target)
        .prev('.panel-heading')
        .find("i.indicator")
        .toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-right glyphicon-chevron-down');
}
$('#accordion').on('hidden.bs.collapse', toggleChevron);
$('#accordion').on('shown.bs.collapse', toggleChevron);
```

```html
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1 
        </a><i class="indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down  pull-right"></i>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
           Collapsible Group Item #2 
        </a><i class="indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right  pull-right"></i>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3 
        </a><i class="indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up pull-right"></i>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use CSS transform to rotate the image on toggle

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<a class="arrow" href="#">        
    <img class="arrow-img rotate2" src="http://www2.psd100.com/ppp/2013/11/0601/Small-down-arrow-icon-1106011554.png" />        
</a>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('.arrow').on("click", function (event) {
    $('.arrow-img').toggleClass('rotate');
    $('.arrow-img').toggleClass('rotate2');
});
```

**CSS**

```
.rotate {
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
    /*transform: rotate(180deg);*/
    transition: .3s;
}
.rotate2 {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    transition: .3s;
}
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/pjh04zew/)